# Combinatorics and Linear Alegbra

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

$$T = \{1011, 0112, 2101\} \subset Z_3^4$$

Is there any efficient way to find the span for set T other than checking all 27 possibility? If so, how to do it?

Comment: $1011+2101=0112$ so the span of $T$ is two dimensional; what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: I am looking for the spans of the set T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, $0112=1011+2101$, so the span of $T$ is simply the span of the set $\{1011,2101\}$. It’s easy to check that neither of these vectors is a multiple of the other, so this set is linearly independent, and the span of $T$ is the set of all vectors

$$a\cdot1011+b\cdot2101$$

such that $a,b\in\Bbb Z_3$. For most purposes that’s a perfectly adequate description, but if you want to list all nine of them, it’s easy enough to do:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
a\backslash b&0&1&2\\ \hline
0&0000&2101&1202\\
1&1011&0112&2210\\
2&2022&1120&0221\\
\end{array}$$